# How to format the email content using mailx command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, mailx

I'm trying to send this content using mailx command in bash script. I could see spaces between each lines. How should I remove spaces between each line and the content to look in good format?

```
echo "Hello there,
      Please find the attachment.
      Email content is having spaces between the lines. I want the spaces to be removed.
      Thanks"| mailx -s "Test Email" "${attachments[@]}" "abc@gmail.com""
```

Any guidance please.

**Mailx command**

```
echo "Hello there,
      Please find the attachment.
      Email content is having spaces between the lines. I want the spaces to be removed.
      Thanks"| mailx -s "Test Email" "${attachments[@]}" "abc@gmail.com""
```

I want the email content to be well formatted. Thanks!

Comment: How you _view_ the content of the email is enterily up to the software you are using to render it. Does the source of sent email has newlines bewteen lines?

Comment: It got fixed. Thanks!